# Integrity Error: null value in column "notification_type_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework and Django per say. I have the following Model Class :

```
class NotificationType(LogModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Name")
    frequency = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    choices=NotificationFrequency.CHOICES,
    verbose_name="notification_frequency")

    active = models.BooleanField(default=1)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'notificaiton_type'
    verbose_name = 'NotificationType'
    verbose_name_plural = 'NotificationTypes'
    ordering = ('-id',)

def __str__(self):
    return "{}{}".format(self.name, self.frequency)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Notification(LogModel):
    notification_type = models.ForeignKey(NotificationType)
    property_info = models.ForeignKey(PropertyInfo)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Notification Description")
    action = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'notification'
    verbose_name = 'Notification'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Notifications'
    ordering = ('-id',)

def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.description)
```

And My Serializers and Viewsets for the same are as follows :

```
class NotificationTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = NotificationType
    fields = ('name', 'frequency', 'active')


class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    property_info = PropertyInfoSerializer(read_only=True)
    notification_type = NotificationTypeSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
```

views.py :

```
class NotificationCRUDView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Notification
    serializer_class = serializers.Notification
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, pk, property_id):  #
        serializer = serializers.NotificationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My urls.py file contains the following url pattern:

```
url(r'^notification/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<property_id>[0-9]+)/$', NotificationCRUDView.as_view(), name="notification-crud-view")
```

Now whenever I am trying to do a POST call using the url path 
/api/v1/notification/pk/property_id {where pk and property_id} passed as url parameter. I am getting the above mentioned error. 
Can anybody please help me with this. TIA. :)

Comment: I think you need to fix the indentation of the source code, if not very readable.

Comment: and include the url details.

Comment: You are not making use of `pk` and `property_id` passed to view function, DRF won't handle that for you.

Comment: Ouch! My bad. Thanks for the help @Saurabh

Answer (score 2):

> Now whenever I am trying to do a POST call using the url path /api/v1/notification/pk/property_id {where pk and property_id} passed as url parameter.

In `POST` call, you don't pass the data in url. It must be passed as request body.

`POST` `/api/v1/notifications/`

Request body:

```
{
  "property_info": "<id>",
  "property_type": "<id>"
}
```

In the `ListCreateAPIView`, there is no `post` method, if you want to override the view for a `POST` call make use of `def create(self, request):` method.

Have a look at the implementation[1] of `CreateModelMixin`.

[1] https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L14-L23
[2] http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview